# Displaying different models data in text boxes in different situatoins

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using mvc4 with razor.I am having my view code in my view i am using two models when i run the application its giving the error like below.

> CS0135: 'Tuple' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Tuple'

Answer (score 0):

I guess somewhere in your view you have used a strongly typed helper with a lambda expression using the reserved Model keyword. This is an example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Tuple => Tuple.SomeProperty)
```

Change the name of the var in the lambda expression like that:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.SomeProperty)
```